# Transforming a sum over quantized modes into an integral

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Let's consider quantized modes $\vec{k}$ in a volume $V$.

Why does

$\frac{1}{V} \sum_{\vec{k}} \rightarrow \frac{1}{(2 \pi)^3} \int d^3k$

hold for the limit $V \rightarrow \infty$?

I'm especially interested in why the prefactors have these values.

Comment: You might want to read about Riemann sums

Comment: Each of discrete $\vec{k}$ points shares the volume $V_{\vec{k}}=(2\pi)^3/V$ in the momentum space. Now replace the function value by its average over small volume: $f(\vec{k})\approx V_\vec{k}^{-1}\int_{V_\vec{k}}f(\vec{k})d\vec{k}$. Hence $V^{-1}\sum_\vec{k}f(\vec{k})\approx V^{-1}V(2\pi)^{-3}\sum_{\vec{k}}\int_{V_{\vec{k}}}f(\vec{k})d\vec{k}$. Canceling $V$ and summing integrals over small volumes $V_{\vec{k}}$ to the total integral over all $\vec{k}$ we get the result. See also: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/294279/why-this-is-the-density-of-points-in-k-space/294291#294291